# Should we handle Certificate/Public Key pinning for external https services?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, certificate-pinning, public-key-pinning

I am writing an Android app that will make some http requests to external HTTPS restful resources - https://external_server/resources ( I have no control of the external Servers )

I am thinking to handle Certificate/Public Key Pinning for the external_server server.

A question popup in my mind: What if the external_server changes the SSL certificate/public key? If the certificate/public key changed. I have to re-deploy my app?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use certificate pinning for services/certificates which you don't own or control, because your app will be quickly broken when service update their certificate and you will have to ***quickly*** update your app on all clients. Moreover, you cannot rely on a specific issuer, because the owner may elect to change their SSL certificate provider.

In your case, you should rely on general SSL certificate validation routine for such services.

Comment: Thank you @CryptoGuy. Do you have any resources of general SSL certificate validation routine?

Comment: It depends on a platform you are using. Many major platforms have libraries to perform certificate validation and which you should use upon connection to verify whether the you are connected to the right resource and your connection is secure.